# significance of final reference variable

Tags: java, string

```
String a="A";
String b="B";
final String c="C";
final String d="D";

String e=a+b;
String f=a+b;
System.out.println(e==f);//false

String g=c+d;
String h=c+d;
System.out.println(g==h);//true
```

Why it is so? String objects are created in a special memory are called string constant pool. But here what is the significance of final variable.

Comment: Final means that the variable can't be altered once initialized.  Indirectly this means that the compiler MAY statically compute the values of expressions using the variable.  And any string value so pre-computed would be interned, allowing the `==` test to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler sees that c and d are final. This means that the compiler knows that c and d will never change. It thus compiles the code to

```
String g = "CD"; 
String h = "CD";
```

g and h are thus two references to the same STring literal, which is interned.

He can't optimize e and f the same way, because a and b are not final and can thus change.

Comment: thanx! but can you please tell me what is interned string.

Answer (score 4):

The final keyword prevents you from **reassigning** the variable to a *different instance* of String.  So while a `String` itself is immutable, a variable that references it can be changed unless explicitly marked with final.

Now, I'm less definite on the exact semantics of what you're experiencing here.  But in general, since the variable is final, `c+d` can now be treated as a compiler constant (it can never have a value other than `"CD"`.  The value is computed at compile time and it can itself be treated as a constant which is put into the pool of interned Strings.

Answer (score 1):

`final` means that you won't be able to modify the value of this String later in your program. Also:

> If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of
>   the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the
>   variable will always refer to the same object. ([source](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html))

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler sees that you have declared your variables as `final` (making them constants, rather than variables), computes `c+d` at compile time, and internalizes the result.